# How to preserve variable value between function calls in vba module?

Tags: vba, variables, module, global

I've created module in vba. I have two functions "AddDropDowns" and "RemoveDropDowns". In first function I would like to store a value in a variable that would be accessible in second function at a later time. I declared a variable called "DropDownsCounter" in the same module as these two functions are in, but the variable does not preserve it's value between function calls. My question is why and how to achieve this? Code of this module is below.

```
    Option Explicit    
        Private DropDownsCounter As Integer
        Public Const QueryAttributes = "Query1:Query2:Query3:Query4:Query5"

        Private Const DropDownsWidth = 70
        Private Const DropDownsHeight = 16.5    
        Function AddDropDowns()
            DropDownsCounter = DropDownsCounter + 1
            Dim QueryAttributesArray() As String
            Dim NumberOfDropDowns As Integer
            QueryAttributesArray() = Split(QueryAttributes, ":")
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Dim x As Integer
            For x = 0 To UBound(QueryAttributesArray)
                Dim Name As String
                Name = "DropDown_" & (NumberOfDropDowns + x)
                Dim CmbBox As OLEObject
                Set CmbBox = Worksheets("Poizvedba").OLEObjects.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
                With CmbBox
                    .Left = GetLastDropDownLeftPos(DN)
                    .Top = Range(DNStartCell).Top + x * DropDownsHeight
                    .Width = DropDownsWidth
                    .Height = DropDownsHeight
                    .Name = Name
                End With
            Next x
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End Function

    Function RemoveDropDowns()
        Dim QueryAttributesArray() As String
        Dim LastDropDown As Integer
        DropDownsCounter = DropDownsCounter - 9
        QueryAttributesArray() = Split(QueryAttributes, ":")
        Dim OleObj As OLEObject
        For Each OleObj In Worksheets("Poizvedba").OLEObjects
            Dim SplittedObjectName() As String
            SplittedObjectName() = Split(OleObj.Name, "_")
            If SplittedObjectName(0) = "DropDown" Then
                LastDropDown = SplittedObjectName(1)
            End If
        Next OleObj
        Dim StartIndexToRemove As Integer
        Dim EndIndexToRemove As Integer
        StartIndexToRemove = LastDropDown - UBound(QueryAttributesArray)
        EndIndexToRemove = LastDropDown
        Dim Sh As OLEObject
        For Each Sh In Worksheets("Poizvedba").OLEObjects
            Dim x As Integer
            For x = StartIndexToRemove To EndIndexToRemove
                If Sh.Name = "DropDown_" & x Then
                    Sh.Delete
                Exit For
                End If
            Next x
        Next Sh
    End Function

Private Function GetLastDropDownLeftPos(ByVal DropDownCategory As String) As Integer
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = Range("A4").Width + Range("B4").Width + DropDownsWidth * DropDownsCounter
    GetLastDropDownLeftPos = pos
End Function
```

**New code that still loses variable value**

**Worksheet code:**

```
Public QueryDropDownsCollection As New Collection

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim NewQuery As QueryDropDown
    Set NewQuery = New QueryDropDown
    QueryDropDownsCollection.Add NewQuery
    Call NewQuery.Initialize(1, 20, 20, 70, 17, 9)
    NewQuery.AddDropDowns
End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    QueryDropDownsCollection(QueryDropDownsCollection.Count - 1).RemoveDropDowns
End Sub
```

**Class Code:**

```
Private pID As Integer
Private pDropDownsWidth As Integer
Private pDropDownsHeight As Integer
Private pLeftPos As Integer
Private pTopPos As Integer
Private pNumberOfDropDowns As Integer
Private pDropDownNames() As String

Property Get ID() As Integer
    ID = pID
End Property

Private Const DropDownsWidth = 70
Private Const DropDownsHeight = 16.5

Public Sub Initialize(ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal LeftPos As Integer, ByVal TopPos As Integer, ByVal DropDownsWidth As Integer, ByVal DropDownsHeight As Integer, ByVal NumberOfDropDowns As Integer)
    pID = ID
    pLeftPos = LeftPos
    pTopPos = TopPos
    pDropDownsWidth = DropDownsWidth
    pDropDownsHeight = DropDownsHeight
    pNumberOfDropDowns = NumberOfDropDowns
    pSheet = Sheet
End Sub

Function AddDropDowns()
    For x = 0 To (pNumberOfDropDowns - 1)
        Dim Name As String
        Name = "DropDown_" & pID & "_" & x
        ReDim Preserve pDropDownNames(0 To x)
        pDropDownNames(x) = Name
        With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
            .Left = LeftPos
            .Top = pTopPos + x * pDropDownsHeight
            .Width = pDropDownsWidth
            .Height = pDropDownsHeight
            .Name = Name
            With .Object
                .AddItem "Krneki1"
            End With
        End With
    Next x
End Function

Function RemoveDropDowns()
    Dim Sh As OLEObject
    For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        Dim x As Integer
        For x = 0 To pNumberOfDropDowns
            If Sh.Name = pDropDownNames(x) Then
                Sh.Delete
            Exit For
            End If
        Next x
    Next Sh
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem with preserving global variables between function calls lies in the dynamically adding OLEObjects to worksheet. When OLEObject is added from the VBA code to Worksheet, the project needs to recompile, because the OLEObject itself becomes a property of the project. It the process of recompiling, it losses all the variable values. Some references to this problem that I also found:

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/dynamically-adding-activex-controls-via-vba-kills-global-vba-heap-t3763287p2.html

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_23574623.html

Answer (score 0):

The variable DropDownsCounter should be incremented by each call of AddDropDowns(), 
it is only used in GetLastDropDownLeftPos(), but not in RemoveDropDowns().

In AddDropDowns() the variable NumberOfDropDowns is a local variable, 
In RemoveDropDowns() the variable NumberOfDropDowns is implicitly global variable.

Have you confused NumberOfDropDowns with DropDownsCounter variable ?

In all your VBA code, you should declare explicitly your variables, by adding on the header of a module:

```
Option Explicit
```

This will give compiling error of your code for debugging.

Comment: DropDownsCounter variable is incremented by each call of AddDropDowns() (See first line of the function - DropDownsCounter = DropDownsCounter + 1). Yes I forgot to delete the local NumberOfDropDowns variable, and forgot to change the name of the NumberOfDropDowns to DropDownsCounter in RemoveDropDowns() function. But that still does not work.

Comment: Is it possible that it has something to do with error "Can't enter break mode at this time"???

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a class module to manage the drop downs.  You can then instance it with a Public, Module level declaration in an ordinary module.  The properties and internal variables will retain their values between calls until the project is reset by an End statement or by VBE reset.

Comment: All the variables loses their values even if I create new instance of the class and store it to global variable. Is it possible that when adding programatically ActiveX controllers, END statement is called on the end. Or maybe on each ActiveX Button click event, END statement is called??? I've added newly designed code in original post.

Comment: OK, you used a Public Collection... that's a cool idea.  If you tried to declare an individual instance in the worksheet module you would get a compilation error so maybe that's the problem and its masked by the indirect instancing in the collection.
I know that the individual instancing works - retaining values etc. - if you put the Public declaration in an ordinary module.
I therefore suggest that you move your Worksheet code into an ordinary module and see if that gets you going.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit rambling...

Move your Worksheet code into an ordinary module.

Comment: As I guessed before, dynamically adding ActiveX controllers somehow calles END statement which causes that global variables does not retain it's values. I tested that simply by commenting out NewQuery.AddDropDowns function call in which OLEObjects are dynamically added to worksheet.